# Extracting subnet in php from a string

Tags: php

I am using this code to extract the IP Address from a string:

```
preg_match( '/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/', '192.168.1.1', $right)
echo $right;
```

Now if I want to extract a subnet mask from a string (like this one for example, `192.168.1.1/12`) how can I do that with pregmatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
preg_match( '/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3})/', '192.168.1.1/12', $right);
var_dump($right[2]);
```